# Unable to Share from Latest ShareButton CodenameOne api

Tags: android, facebook, java-me, codenameone

I have imported the Facebook Demo into netbeans and followed the guidelines as mentioned in the developer guide and as well as set required facebook permissions. But I'm failing to share the text on to the wall, where as am able to retrieve friends list, profile info and news feed.

```
final ShareButton share = new ShareButton();
final TextArea t = new TextArea(" This is sample text from using CodenameOne api");
t.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            share.setTextToShare(t.getText());
        }
    });
c.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, t);
share.setTextToShare(t.getText());
```

Is there anything which im missing to integrate or set any additional permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear if this is in the device or in the simulator. On iOS/Android the native share functionality is used and the behavior is very different from the simulator.

Facebook recently made changes to the way permissions work and essentially blocked support for non-iOS/Android platforms. This still worked after the blocks but its possible that it stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shai. I was testing on simulator. And if they really block non Android n iOS, authentication and friends feed should not work too. I'm just having problem with share functionality.

Comment: No. The change Facebook made was in the publish permissions which now require a very special process only supported by native login on devices. You can still read data like before but if you want to post anything you need to go thru a special API.